# Stop a sticky element at a certain spot other than the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a sticky sidebar that sticks 100px from the top of the page, the problem is when I scroll, the sticky element scrolls to the very top of the page, then jumps down to the 100px.

Is there a way to make it stop once it get to the 100px mark?

The div wrapper is "aside". I'm using this script from stickyjs.com
http://static.tumblr.com/zvesamf/5veoajatd/jquery.sticky.js

Along with:

```
$(window).load(function(){
      $("aside").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    });
```

**The full html + css code is [here](http://jsbin.com/webivikeve/edit?html,css,output).**

Comment: Yes add a margin-top of 100px

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin-top of 100px to your sticky element

Comment: I added the css associated with it. I have the margin-top set to 100, and it does work, but it scrolls to the very top and then jumpy down to the margin.